# Celery: limit memory usage (large number of django installations)

Tags: celery, django-celery

- we're having a setup with a large number of separate django installations on a single box. each of these have their own code base & linux user.
- we're using celery for some asynchronous tasks.
- each of the installations has its own setup for celery, i.e. its own celeryd & worker.
- the amount of asynchronous tasks per installation is limited, and not time-critical.
- when a worker starts it takes about 30mb of memory. when it has run for a while this amount may grow (presumably due to fragmentation).

the last bulletpoint has already been (somewhat) solved by settings --maxtasksperchild to a low number (say 10). This ensures a restart after 10 tasks, after which the memory at least goes back to 30MB.

However, each celeryd is still taking up a lot of memory, since the minimum amount of workers appears to be 1 as opposed to 0. I also imagine running `python manage.py celery worker` does not lead to the smallest-possible footprint for the celeryd, since the full stack is loaded even if the only thing that happens is checking for tasks.

In an ideal setup, I'd like to see the following: a process that has a very small memory footprint (100k or so) is looking at the queue for new tasks. when such a task arises, it spins up the (heavy) full django stack in a separate process. and when the worker is done, the heavy process is spun down.

Is such a setup configurable using (somewhat) standard celery? If not, what points of extension are there?

we're (currently) using celery 3.0.17 and the associated django-celery.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand - you have a lot of different django codebases, each with their own celery, and they take up too much memory when running on a single box simultaneously, all waiting for a celery job to come down the pipe? How many celery instances are we talking about here?

In my experience, you're using django celery in a very different way than it was designed for - all of your different django projects should be condensed to a few (or a single) project(s), composed of multiple applications. Then you set up a small number of queues to field celery tasks from the different apps - this way, you only have as many dormant celery threads taking up 30mb as you have queues, and a single queue can handle multiple tasks (from multiple apps if you want). The memory issue should go away.

To reiterate - you only need one celeryd, driving multiple workers. This way your bottleneck is job concurrency, not dormant memory needs.

Why do you need so many django installations? Please let me know if I'm missing something, or if you need clarification.

Comment: Ca. 50 installations per box. The various installations of Django Celery correspond to various django installations.

My scenario is not too different from "shared hosting" (although I share with myself). I.e. the various Django projects correspond to various sites (apps) that are distinct.

Comment: then I think you'll need to rearchitect such that the celery jobs are separate from the django installs - maybe have a single "admin" django project that manages celery jobs, so that you only need a few workers active at once.